# UIPopoverController callbalck for end of animation

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, uipopovercontroller

UIPopoverController changes it size then keyboard is shown, and change it back then keyboard is hidden for landscape orientation. I need to perform some actions when popup restore it original size, so I am looking for callback on end of popup resize animation.

I've already tried to catch notification that keyboard is hidden, but this does not help - popup change it size **after** keyboard become hidden. I also tried to 
set animation delegate to UIView, but looks like this works only for custom animations.

Currently I end up with performSelectorAfterDelay, called at callback for UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, but this solution does not look nice. May be someone can point me for another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're providing a custom `UIView` for `UIPopoverController`, you can override a couple different layout functions in `UIView`: `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

If you're using the default view, you can leverage KVO to listen for changes to the views `bounds`.

`addObserver(popoverController.contentViewControler.view, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)`

Comment: Thanks! I missed out that viewDidLayoutSubviews() will be called after finishing view animation to final size.